# NullPointerException when opening SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying to open a SQLite database, but this NullPointerException keeps on poping in.

Here is the Code for the java file:

```
    public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;

@Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

      setContentView(R.layout.question);
      currentGame = ((QuizApplication) getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
      currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();

  Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
  nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


      setQuestions();

  }


  private void setQuestions() {

    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
            qText.setText(question);


            List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
            TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
            option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

         TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
         option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

         TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
         option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

         TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
             option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));   
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (!checkAnswer()) return;



            if (currentGame.isGameOver()){

                Intent i = new Intent(this, QuizMenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }


   }






@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



private boolean checkAnswer() {

    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer==null){

        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {

            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();

        }
        else{

            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();

        }
        return true;
    }
}


private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    RadioButton c4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.isChecked())
    {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.isChecked())
    {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.isChecked())
    {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c4.isChecked())
    {
        return c4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
    }


  }
```

As well as the errors that show up in the LogCat that stop me from continuing :

```
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{QuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at ....QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:38)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-17 14:40:22.845: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: A wild guess would be that your Button could not be found (using `findViewById()` and therefor throws the NPE when you try to add the `OnClickListener`. But you you should check line 38 for yourself...

Comment: This line: `at ....QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:38)
` tells me that the error is occurring on line 38 of your code, but since the import declarations have been removed, we can't really pinpoint that line.  You should examine that line, and if you're still having trouble, edit your question to call out that line or include the imports.  I suspect @LukasKnuth is right; it's either that or currentGame is null.

Comment: A small correction which is unrelated to your problem. When you are implementing the `OnClickListener` in your main class why have an anonymous inner class for `nextBtn.setOnClickListener()`? You can write that code in the `onClick(View arg0)` of your main class.

Comment: I have doubt in currentGame = ((QuizApplication) getApplication()).getCurrentGame(); can you check if currentGame is not null?

Comment: the line for the error 38 is this -   
currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion(); 
but az Vipul Shah said it might be the the previous one but how do i check if its null - i havnt declared it null anywhere? Cheers

Comment: I've tried to use if statements where there were errors on my app, but it is actually working - there were no questions and answers in the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not typecast getApplication() to QuizApplication

Change your code to following.

```
currentGame = ((QuizApplication) getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
if(currentGame!=null)
{
  currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
}
```

Also if you solve NPE then you will get `ActivityNotFoundException` in following block.You must specify Target Activity or action in intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: haha, now i have problems on NPE as well:
       setQuestions();
and :
      String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";

any ideas? and the code u gave me actually does the currentQ function right? Thanx a lot